# How do I get over-withheld tax from 2017-2022 back as an non-resident alien?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, withholding-tax

I’ve worked as a freelancer from Europe with an American art agency for years and still get some royalties.

In 2017 they suddenly changed the tax withholding from 0% to 10% this was not correct but I didn’t know I did ask about the change in early 2018 at the time I thought they were right until I quit the agency and started direct freelance jobs with American business and they did not withhold the tax since my country has a tax treaty 0%.
Since I still got some royalties through the agency I asked about it and now they will pay the overwithheld tax for 2023 but what about the previous years?

Now I did make it clear that I want a solution for the prior years.
What is the process for this employer who has wrongly overwithheld tax until this year that I told them it’s not correct (I had also asked about it in Jan 2018 email).

What can I demand from them?

Thank you,
Jaime

Comment: Tax withholding is not the same as the tax that is due. Tax withholding is just an amount you prepay to approximate the tax that you owe. The actual tax you owe may be more or less than the tax withheld. You file a tax return to reconcile the difference.

Comment: Yes but I did not live nor did I work in US and I am not an US citizen, I pay tax in my country. So actually this probably was not even us-based income if I’m correct this is foreign based income because I did all the freelance work in the country I’m. A citizen in.

Comment: According to Publication 519, [rents and royalties](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2022_publink1000222241) from property located in the US, as well as from use in the US of intangible property, is US income. I am not sure if that is your situation.

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer - you will need to file 1040-NR returns, for past years. https://www.irs.gov/filing/amended-return-frequently-asked-questions Highly recommend you file all years in a single paper package, and mail it to IRS. Include a cover letter that explains your situation, accepts that delay in filing is due to your own ignorance, be thankful for the opportunity to have your returns reviewed, and then wait patiently for them to assess you. Ultimately there will be a human being reviewing your package, and you want to make their job easy and pleasant.

Answer (score 2):

You should have received a [form 1042-S](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1042-s) from them for each year. With this form you then file a tax return with the IRS (form [1040-NR](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1040-nr)) on which you show your US-sourced income, your tax withheld, your treaty claims, and the refund you're entitled to. The IRS will mail you a refund check.

Note that there may be a statute of limitations for older years (usually claims for refund are only allowed within 3 years of the tax return due date).

The employer can help you fix the current year, but not the prior years - that money has been sent to the IRS already.

Comment: I never received any tax forms from the agency I got freelance jobs from I only once had to fill out W-8Ben forms

Comment: If they had tax withholdings they must have provided you some form, otherwise how do you know they withheld anything? It has to be either 1099, 1042-S, or W2, depending on the situation. In your case it should be 1042-S.

Comment: No I haven’t received any of these, I only got statements from my freelance jobs and next to the amount a deducted 10% withholding tax. I don’t think it’s actually us based income because I live and work in the Netherlands shouldn’t it have been foreign based income in the first place I never understood why they suddenly started witholding tax.

Comment: @Jaime I'm sure there are tax statements in NL that a payer would need to provide either. If the payer is in the US, I doubt they'd withhold anything for NL. You'll need to ask them what it is and where are the required tax forms, otherwise you won't be able to claim the refund from the tax authorities. What I described is how it's supposed to work by law, if your "agency" is taking a cut from your money without providing any required tax form - they're just stealing from you.